# Error converting data type when using multiple WHERE statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that works fine when the WHERE statement contains only one statement, but not when it contains both statements at the same time. When I use both WHERE statements, I get "Error converting data type to varchar to numeric." (The error is occurring in the second SELECT statement, not in the CTE).

This code is what I want:

```
;WITH cte_1 as(
SELECT  EVENT_ID
        ,CLIENT_ID
        ,convert(varchar(10), E.STARTDATE, 101) as R106_DATE
FROM    SCEVENT
WHERE   STARTDATE>='06/01/2016' AND STARTDATE<='06/30/2016'
        and SVC_ID=106
)

SELECT  R.*
        ,convert(varchar(10), S.BEG_DATE, 101)  as SVC_DATE
        ,S.UNIT_ID
FROM    cte_1  R
        JOIN CDCLSVC S
          on R.CLIENT_ID=S.CLIENT_ID
WHERE   R106_DATE<=BEG_DATE
        and UNIT_ID=251
```

If I include one or the other WHERE statements, it works fine. But if I have both of those statements, I get an error.

(The desired result is a list of people who had a service at unit 251 after they had a service code (SVC_ID) 106.)

Thoughts?

Comment: what's the datatype on `CDCLSVC.CLIENT_ID`  and `SCEVENT.CLIENT_ID`

Comment: CLIENT_ID is numeric in both data sets. UNIT_ID is also numeric.

Comment: So, my code above will work if I change it from "and UNIT_ID=251" to "and UNIT_ID>=251".  It works with the > sign. But, of course, this is not what I want.

Comment: Ok so it's not the JOIN. How about `SCEVENT.SVC_ID` and  `CDCLSVC.UNIT_ID`

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: What error do you get?  If you take the first query from the CTE, does that work OK on its own?  Also, R106_DATE is actually a varchar, so what is beg_date?  I think you probably want these both to be dates otherwise your results may be wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code so that it's not converting the date until after the match (excellent point, @JonathanShields) but I kept getting the error message.

I ended up changing my date range to a longer period of time, and suddenly it worked. I guess there were no records in the given time frame that met both criteria, but instead of returning a result of 0 records it gave me the error message.

Thanks for everyone's help.